# This code doesn't work on Jquery 3

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code:

```
save: function (secc, next) {

$.snackbar({content: 'Guardando cambios...'});
$('.ac_input, .cuenta-save-'+secc).removeClass('input-incorrect');

if (typeof next == 'undefined') var next = false;
params = Array();
params.push('save='+secc);

$('.cuenta-save-'+secc).each(function(){
    if (($(this).attr('type') != 'checkbox' && $(this).attr('type') != 'radio') || $(this).attr('checked')) params.push($(this).attr('name')+'='+encodeURIComponent($(this).val()));
});

var cuenta_url = global_data.url + '/cuenta.php?action=save&ajax=true';

loading.show();
$.ajax({
    type: 'post', 
    url: cuenta_url, 
    data: params.join('&'), 
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (r) {
        //$('#prueba').html(r.html);
        if (r.error) {
            if (r.field) $('input[name='+r.field+']').focus().addClass('input-incorrect');
            cuenta.alert(secc, r.error)
        }
        else {
            if (next) cuenta.next(secc > 1 && secc < 5);
            cuenta.alert(secc, 'Los cambios han sido guardados exitosamente!');
            if(r.porc != null) {
                $('#porc-completado-label').html('Perfil completo al ' + r.porc + '%');
                $('.progress .porc-completado-barra').css('width', r.porc + '%');
                $('.progress .porc-completado-barra').html(r.porc + '%');
                $('.progress .porc-completado-barra').attr( "aria-valuenow", r.porc);
            }
        }
        window.location.hash = 'alert-cuenta';
        loading.hide(); 
    }
});
}
```

That in Jquery 1.7.4 works perfectly with this:

```
                                        {foreach from=$tsPData.gustos key=val item=text}
                                       <input type="checkbox" id="g_{$val}" name="g_{$val}" class=" cuenta-save-2" value="1" {if $tsPerfil.p_gustos.$val == 1}checked="checked"{/if}>
                                        <label for="g_{$val}">{$text}</label><br/>
                                        {/foreach}
```

That finally is Ajax Interpreted:

```
for($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++) $gustos[$i] = $_POST['g_'.$i], true);
```

But in Jquery 3 doesn't work anymore with the code.
It doesn't save anything in the database :/, but the another things, yes.

Which is the problem, is any function deprecated?

Thank you!

Comment: So what does happen? What errors are thrown? What specifically doesn't work? *"doesn't work"* is a virtually meaningless problem statement

Comment: any errors in the console? likely a deprecated method

Comment: No errors :/, in the console at least...